# Maven doesn't generate the "persistence.xml" file

Tags: java, maven-2, jpa

I read [this article](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) on the maven project web page that lists the different directory layouts (like: src/main/resources which is for Application/Library resources).

The problem is that when I run the following command ([found here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)):

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

the src/main/resources/META-INF directory isn't created. It's important for me because I'd like to reach the "persistence.xml" that is found in that directory.

Should I add an option in the mvn command? How can I automatically generate the "src/main/resources" that contains the "META-INF/persistence.xml" file?

Thank you,
Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The problem is that when I run the following command (...) the src/main/resources/META-INF directory isn't created. It's important for me because I'd like to reach the "persistence.xml" that is found in that directory.

The maven quickstart archetype does NOT create `src/main/resources` nor `src/test/resources`. There are several explanations:

- As stated by its name, this archetype allows to **quickstart** a project, it's up to you to shape it.
- Why should this archetype create `src/main/resources` and not, say, `src/main/assembly`?
- Creating empty directories was actually not possible during a long time (see [ARCHETYPE-57](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ARCHETYPE-57)).

In other words, just add `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` manually if you use this archetype.

> Should I add an option in the mvn command? How can I automatically generate the "src/main/resources" that contains the "META-INF/persistence.xml" file?

You can't with this archetype - and I don't really understand why this is a such big issue.

There is a JPA archetype though:

```
mvn archetype:create \
  -DgroupId=com.mycompany.project \
  -DartifactId=my-project-domain \
  -DpackageName=com.company.project.domain \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=com.rfc.maven.archetypes \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=jpa-maven-archetype  \
  -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0  \
  -DremoteRepositories=http://maven.rodcoffin.com/repo
```

That creates the following bootstrap JPA project:

```
$ tree my-project-domain/
my-project-domain/
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── com
    │   │       └── company
    │   │           └── project
    │   │               └── domain
    │   │                   └── User.java
    │   └── resources
    │       └── META-INF
    │           └── persistence.xml
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── company
        │           └── project
        │               └── domain
        │                   ├── DbUnitDataLoader.java
        │                   └── UserTest.java
        └── resources
            └── user.db.xml

16 directories, 6 files
```

Comment: @downvoter Care to explain why this answer deserves a downvote? Can you please show me what part of this answer is incorrect?

Answer (score 4):

Don't be too dependant on maven doing things for you. These archetypes are just there to provide basic templates. If they don't create a file for you, just go ahead and create it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here you used the quickstart archetype which is the sample, more informations [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html).
If you want a Java EE standard layout you shoud use the `maven-archetype-j2ee-simple` archetype :

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-j2ee-simple -DinteractiveMode=false
```