# WEB-INF/config/persistence.xml cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

This is not a duplicate of [Same question but not for a webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191914/meta-inf-persistence-xml-cannot-be-opened-because-it-does-not-exist)

My `persistence.xml` file is located in `wepapp/WEB-INF/config/persistence.xml`

I use annotations to bring it in, I did it this way because I am using hibernate and JPA 2 at the same time. I am cleaning out `hibernateTemplate` but need them to work together for the moment.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("request.repositoryJPA")
@ComponentScan("request.domain, classes.applicant")
@PropertySource("classpath:WEB-INF/config/persistence.xml")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfiguration {
```

Full stack trace:

```
Caused By: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/config/persistence.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:90)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:72)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:58)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally wouldn't bother using a persistence.xml if I was using Spring boot, but if I was I'd load it like this:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html (see the 73.8 Use a traditional persistence.xml).

Why are you using a PropertySource to try and load it ?

Here's how to create one programmatically, no persistence.xml involved (you'd have to adapt it for hibernate):

```
 public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean MyPersistenceUnit() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(aDataSourceYouveCreatedElsewhere);
        em.setPackagesToScan("some package name");
        em.setLoadTimeWeaver(loadTimeWeaver);
        em.setMappingResources("META-INF/orm.xml");

        EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        EclipseLinkJpaDialect dialect = vendorAdapter.getJpaDialect();
        dialect.setLazyDatabaseTransaction(true);

        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(environment.getProperty("some soft coded property"));
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.parseBoolean(environment.getProperty("some handy property to turn on and off showing sql")));

        em.setPersistenceUnitName("whatveryouwanttocallit");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;

    }
```

Comment: This is a legacy project and I am trying to use JPA and Hibernate to gracefully work together. This is my current solution and I am not using spring-boot I am using `<spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>` I would have loved if I could use spring-boot in this project!

Comment: I've changed my answer to demonstrate how to do it without a need for persistence.xml. Of great use is the packages to scan property , which you use instead of listing every entity in the xml file.

Moving to a programmatic approach is much better in the long run, as apart from anything else it's refactor friendly.

Comment: This helped but the root cause was Weblogic. By Default it loaded a javax.persistence.jar file version 1 BUT I need the updated jar file to work with hibernate 4 so I had to edit the `PRE_CLASS` in the config file. JPA 2.1 does not work with old javax.persistence.jar files. However thank you for helping me get rid of more XML as that is always my goal! This had me confused for several days.

Answer (score 1):

`wepapp/WEB-INF/` is not in the classpath. In web application the classpath is `classes` directory in `WEB-INF` folder which is in a `.war` file.

That's an example of my project where `persitence.xml` is placed:

[image]

And then I reference it using: `classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml`. So what you need to do is to make sure your `persitence.xml` file is in the classpath.

If it's maven project just put it somewhere under `resources` directory of your project and it will be automatically included in the classpath. For e.g. `resources/config/persistence.xml` and then reference `classpath:config/persistence.xml`. Otherwise make sure that your `persistence.xml` file ends up in the `classes` directory when the project is built.

Comment: Yes I am using maven. I put the persistence.xml file in `resources` run `mvn clean install` and then ran the project and got the same error. I have confirmed the `.xml` file is in the classes directory in the `target` folder.

Comment: I had to update my `@PropertySource("classpath:persistence.xml")` and it worked sides the `:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:Document root element "persistence", must match DOCTYPE root "null".` error